# Живут или живёт?

Tags: грамматика, глаголы

I have come across this sentence where the verb *жить* is declined for the third person singular:

> Там живёт около 500 человек.

Shouldn't *живут* be grammatically correct since we're talking about more than 2 people?

Comment: Colloquially. the both a correct

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rosenthal et al.:

> Форма единственного числа сказуемого указывает на совместное действие, форма множественного числа – на раздельное совершение действия. Ср.: *Пять солдат отправилось в разведку* (группой). – *Пять солдат отправились в разведку* (каждый с самостоятельным заданием); *К началу экзамена явилось десять студентов. – Десять студентов окончили институт с отличием*.
>
> Ср. также различное согласование однородных сказуемых в одном и том же предложении: *Человек полтораста солдат высыпало из лесу и с криком устремились на вал* (Пушкин) (в первом случае характеризуется совместность действия, во втором – раздельность).

Since this sentence is most probably about the population of a small town, this is more of a collective "action" of living there, and hence the singular is used.